# Splitting & Concatenating a variable to be used in a function

Tags: javascript

I have this code which is a client-side preview of an image before uploading. I have an array of file uploads (6 of them) and need to split and `cssStr` to allow for a variable value.. (`.upload-preview1`, `.upload-preview 2` etc.).

I have tried splitting and concatenating the string this way:

```
var cssStr = ".upload-preview" + "1" + " img";
```

and tried a few other methods including `concat()` .. just can't seem to get it to work. The code as it stands below functions as it should, but does not allow for any alterations in the cssStr variable depending on which item in the array was used (which I will later code in).

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var cssStr = ".upload-preview1 img";
        var preview = $(cssStr);

        $(".file").change(function (event) {
            var input = $(event.currentTarget);
            var file = input[0].files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                image_base64 = e.target.result;
                preview.attr("src", image_base64);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: How are you splitting/making the string? Concatenating strings work as you've described.

Comment: Just as above `var cssStr = ".upload-preview" + "1" + " img";` the function just isn't working.. really confusing as to why, i've used this method plenty of times without problem.

Comment: How is it not working? Are you debugging what `cssStr` is when you concat the string? That works fine http://jsfiddle.net/6zfEk/

Comment: sorry, for some reason it's just decided to work. . . :/

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
$(".file").each(function(idx, el) {
  var cssStr = ".upload-preview" + idx + " img";
  var preview = $(cssStr);
  $(el).change({ <your code here> });
});
```

The each method takes a function with the index of the element and the DOM element itself: http://api.jquery.com/each/.

I'm assuming `.file` is a CSS class on a wrapper of each file input.